# Why do I get this error: form2 not defined

Tags: web2py

My code:

```
def return_post:
    form = SQLFORM(db.post)
    for c in form:
    form1= post.body
    form2 = form1.split()
return dict(form2=form2)
```

In view:

```
{{=form2}}
```

I get the error that form2 is not defined. 
The above is the actual code. I had actually posted this from the Samsung tab and could not get the curly brackets.

Comment: This must not be your actual code -- above your refer to `post.body`, but there is no `post` object defined in your code. Also, if you iterate over `form`, you will only get one top level component, which is a `TABLE` object. Maybe explain more what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `=form2` within curly braces, not parenthesis.

```
{{=form2}}
```

Change it and try again.  If using your tablet, try copy-pasting the above line. That should work.